# POST handler method not being called in Python/Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am trying to parse a POST request in Python using Flask with the code below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/csv', methods=['POST'])
def handle_message():
    print("This print statement never gets called")
    return 'Received !'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run( 
   host="0.0.0.0",
   port=int("5000")
)
```

I am making the POST request from another machine, and I know it is made correctly because I get this on the commandline (though I am not sure what specifically in my code is printing it):

```
10.0.0.36 - - [17/Aug/2017 16:28:49] "POST /csv HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However,the `handle_message` function never seems to be called (the print statement within is never executed). Might anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug mode? It usually won't print unless you turn on debug mode. Also, you can just type `5000`, you don't have to do int("5000")

Comment: `print` is never returned as part of the server response

Answer (score 1):

Your code on my machine:
server side:

```
This print statement never gets called
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 23:46:09] "POST /csv HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

client side, 
command by [httpie](https://httpie.org/)

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/csv
```

response

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 20:46:09 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.15 Python/3.5.3

Received !
```